# textContent display Content only for a while (using addEventListener)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display typed text, but it shows only for a moment - don't know why.

HTML

```
<div>
  <h1 id="ASD"></h1>
</div>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="OUTPUT">
  <input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>
```

CSS

```
div{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

JS

```
let output= document.getElementById('OUTPUT');
const newSubmit = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');

function checkNumber() {
  document.getElementById('ASD').textContent = output.value;
}
newSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkNumber, false);
```

http://codepen.io/Shalahmander/pen/QdKvgJ

Typed text should be display in box after click Submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page is refreshing on the submit click (the form is processed). You can handle `event` object and call `.preventDefault` to cancel the default behavior, like this:

```
let output= document.getElementById('OUTPUT');
const newSubmit = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');

function checkNumber(e) {
  document.getElementById('ASD').textContent = output.value;
  e.preventDefault();
}
newSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkNumber, false);
```

But I suggest using `<button/></button>`or `<input type="button"></input>` if you want to perform another action (than submit your form).

Also, remember to close your tags: `<input>...</input>` or `<input />`.